# F# the namespace or module 'XXXX' is not defined

Tags: asp.net, f#, webforms

I'm trying to create a basic ASP.net f# application and when I'm trying to reference the Youtube .net API I'm getting a "The namespace or module 'Google' is not defined" in my code behind file.

I've used the default ASP web forms template in Visual Studio, removed all of the contents, then loaded in the examples from Expert F#, Chapter 14.  The default examples run fine, the problem only occurs when loading the Google API. The API works fine when I load it through an f# console application.

The first few lines behind file looks like:

```
#light
namespace MyASPApp

open System
open System.Web
open System.Web.UI
open System.Web.UI.WebControls
open Google.YouTube
```

Can anyone think of a resolution to the problem, or anything I could check to understand why its not picking up the Google API?

Comment: just to rule out the obvious: did you add references in your project to Google.GData.YouTube.dll, Google.GData.Client.dll and Google.GData.Extensions.dll ?

Comment: Yes I've added the references. It just doesn't seem to be picking them up, not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 5):

The Google assembly may require that the application not use the Client Profile, which is the default in VS 2010. Try editing the project settings and changing the Target Framework property.

Comment: This has burned me a few times!

Answer (score 2):

Did you check which version of .NET Framework that google assembly is built for? If it .NET 3.5 or .NET 4.0? If that is not set properly too this will occur.

-Fahad