# open c# namespace from same solution, referenced project in f#

Tags: c#, f#, namespaces

I am still trying to get my head around namespaces in referenced projects.

I have a c# project where a namespace ("A") is defined.
I create a F# application, where I reference the c# project.

```
open A
```

leads to the following:

> error FS0039: The namespace or module 'A' is not defined

This is what I have checked:

- The C# and F# project target the same framework (.Net Framework 4.5) ([F# the namespace or module 'XXXX' is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091132/f-the-namespace-or-module-xxxx-is-not-defined))
- The C# and F# project have the same target (Any CPU)
- The C# project is correctly listed among the F# project references
- I am correctly trying to open a namespace (not as in this case: [How to use C# object from F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3901805/how-to-use-c-sharp-object-from-f))
- I am not operating from the FSI (https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632859/difference-in-namespace-reference-between-f-interactive-and-compiled-exe)

MSDN is not much of a help (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd393787.aspx).

Thanks.

[EDIT]

I have started from scratch, so that the example is lean and clean.

The C# project "ClassLibrary1" contains:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

The F# Application is:

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.net
// See the 'F# Tutorial' project for more help.
open ClassLibrary1

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

The error:

> The namespace or module 'ClassLibrary1' is not defined

Comment: Do you definitely have *public* types within that namespace?

Comment: Yes, the namespace contains public classes.

Comment: Can you produce a short but complete example, with both the C# and the F#?

Comment: A = ClassLibrary1 in the example. As said, I have started from scratch to provide a short but complete example. I wanted to make sure that the issue would be insulated from whatever other issue my C# code may have. Thanks.

Comment: There was a comment here that led me on the right path: the answer is building in steps, starting with the C# library. Not sure why the comment has been removed, but hey, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yeah, I think thats because the F# project references the actual DLL and not the project file. I'm not exactly what C# does, but it can reference other projects that aren't built yet.

Comment: This is true. I realized that. Whenever I do make changes in the C# library, I need to rebuild the project to "see" the changes affect my F# code. Hope this will change in the future..

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis Did you ever figure out a good solution to this?  For me, if I'm referencing a c# public static member, I have to fully qualify the name using namespace.TypeName.MemberName or Visual Studio 2019 will yell at me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your reference is a real project references and not just referencing the DLL in the bin\Debug folder.

If you can't get a real project reference to work, make sure the F# project is set to depend on the C# project so that it gets built first by Visual Studio (right-click on the project and go to Project Dependencies then use the tickboxes).

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. All I had to do was make sure my C# project dependencies were all settled, build my C# projects, then the F# project was able to reference the correct dll's.

In Visual Studio, you can right click on each C# project and press build.
In VSCode, you have to use the terminal to navigate to each project and run `dotnet build`.